# Normalize numpy signal (3 dimension array), by axis=2, between -1 to 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array [shape: (100, 11, 1000)], I would like to normalize by axis=2, to values between -1 to 1. Which method should I use to ensure that every signal by batch and channels (axis 0 and 1), where values range between -1 to 1?

*Figure 1:* The data values could range between -20 to 20, for example `plt.plot(data[0,0])`:

[image: signal1]

*Figure 2:* To range between -140 to 140, for example `plt.plot(data[55,3])`:

[image: signal2]

**Update:** MinMaxScaler does not support 3 dimension array:
`Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2.`

**Update:** Applying the following code doesn't produce a similar signal as the input :

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
norm = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

*Figure 3:* the output after applying min-max norm code to input *Figure 1*:

[image: signal3]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MinMaxScaler from sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# create object with feature range of -1, 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))

# transform data
transformed_array = scaler(your_data)
```

If you don't want to use sklearn you could implement it yourself in numpy. Equations above are calculated using the following:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

Docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Answer (score 1):

Just specify `axis=2` in the following formula:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=2)) / (X.max(axis=2) - X.min(axis=2))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

It is absolutely normal that with `axis=0` the signal is distorted, because each point will be normalized compared to the other samples values !